# How to Import OpenZeppelin Contracts with Node.js Environment

Tags: solidity, nodejs

I'm having an issue. I'm attempting to compile my contract with Node.js inside of a VSCode terminal, but my openzeppelin imports aren't being seen, and I'm not sure how to handle them with Node.js. How are these libraries meant to be handled? Am I instead supposed to link directly to their github repos?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

contract MusicNFTMarketplace is ERC721("DAppFi", "DAPP"), Ownable(address(this)) {
...
```

Essentially, when attempting to compile this with a compile.js file, the imports break the solc compiler.

```
component: 'general',
      errorCode: '6275',
      formattedMessage: 'ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File import callback not supported\n' +
        ' --> NFTMusicMarketplace.sol:4:1:\n' +
        '  |\n' +
        '4 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";\n' +
        '  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n' +
        '\n',
      message: 'Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File import callback not supported',
      severity: 'error',
      sourceLocation: [Object],
      type: 'ParserError'
```

For clarity, I have ran `npm install @openzeppelin/contracts` and still receive the same error.

My compile.js looks like this:

```
const path = require("path");
const solc = require("solc");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "build");
const contractFileName = "NFTMusicMarketplace.sol";

fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const musicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", contractFileName);
const source = fs.readFileSync(musicPath, "utf8");


const input = {
  language: "Solidity",
  sources: {},
  settings: {
    metadata: {
      useLiteralContent: true
    },
    outputSelection: {
      "*": {
        "*": ["*"]
      }
    }
  }
};

input.sources[contractFileName] = {
  content: source
};

const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
console.log(output);
const contracts = output.contracts[contractFileName];

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);


// Extract and write the JSON representations of the contracts to the build folder.
for (let contract in contracts) {
  if (contracts.hasOwnProperty(contract)) {
    fs.outputJsonSync(path.resolve(buildPath, `${contract}.json`), contracts[contract]);
  }
}
```

and package.json:

```
{
  "name": "music-marketplace",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "dev": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^5.0.0",
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^2.0.11",
    "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.3",
    "solc": "^0.8.21",
    "web3": "^1.7.4"
  }
}
```

The folder structure is something like this, because I plan on adding a front-end to it with Next.

```
|components
|ethereum
|--------contracts
|node_modules
|pages
|test
|package.json
```

Comment: This error is related to solidity compiler settings.
Try this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67321111/file-import-callback-not-supported

Comment: Unfortunately, the highest rated answer there did not work. I keep seeing the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's weird. That's how a million other projects do it successfully.

Maybe check your Node version?

I also wonder what your `compile.js` does. Are you using something like Hardhat? If not, I recommend using it - it makes life easier.

Comment: I am not using Hardhat. Is it generally recommended to use it?

Comment: IT manages this kind of things for you. Yes, using something like Hardhat is highly recommended when developing contracts

Comment: So I recreated my setup with Hardhat and it seems to work perfectly fine now. A good lesson for the future, I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

What is your folder organisation, and what's your package.json file? Using hardhat is indeed very much recommended.

Comment: I've added that info in the original post.